# create associative array while looping through collection in magneto 2

Tags: php, json, magento2

i have a collection object

```
$di=array();

$products= $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('entity_id','22');

foreach ($products as $key => $value)

 { # code...  }
```

I want to know how to loop through this collection and create associative array ..and if result has multiple rows how to loop through it.

As final result i should get the array as

```
{key=>value, key1=>value1}
```

Comment: Do you want to create a JSON object as the result (which would be `{key1: value1, key2: value2}`) or do you need a PHP array? If the second option would fit, remove the JSON tag from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `getCollection()` already returns an array of elements of the given collection, with all its attributes (`addAttributeToSelect('*')`), so you are already receiving an array of objects rather than a multi-dimensional array.

In the simplest of all cases and if you need a JSON array containing all the products with all attributes, it would be as simple as this:

```
$jsonArray= json_encode($products); // converts all elements into a JSON representation
```

If you would need an associative array of elements rather than an array of objects, typecast the objects:

```
$assocArray= array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
  $assocArray[]= (array) $product; // type-casting to array
}
```

If you want to iterate over each property of each product (I wouldn't know why you would want that), here's that version:

```
$assocArray= array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
  $rowArray= array();
  foreach ($product as $key => $val) {
    $rowArray[$key]= $val;
  }
  $assocArray[]= $rowArray;
}
```

Hope that gives you an idea of how collections can be used in Magento work.

Comment: thanks Sascha.. $jsonArray= json_encode($products) ,,.foreach($products as $product)  working very fine.i could go ahead in project with this explanation. but loop using key and value is returning emphty array.but any how my problem solved.thank you.this explanation would be more usefull for magento beginners